# How to make an invisible link?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, invisible

Can a link be made invisible but still return a backlink from a website?
I've been looking in various places but I have not found the html I need.

Please help

Comment: are you talking on a `web` application / winforms/ ...???? on a web you should use `CSS` with overlapping CSS for the hyperlink

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!